# How to put two IconButtons in the same Column (AppBar and Body)?

Tags: flutter, dart, width, appbar, iconbutton

Is there any way how to have an IconButton in the AppBar and an IconButton in the Body the same column width? The splash radius should be default. Please have a look on a screenshot at the following link for an overview.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0CiM.png

Comment: Hi Fritz, welcome to our community. Would you like to add your code on the question? That would help us to do a better answer to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the solution that you are looking for, because your question is not clear 100%.

By default IconButton are aligned to the AppBar actions. You can check it on this sample:

https://dartpad.dev/?id=0199904cac2a477c420efe473ed21319

The result is this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use SilverAppbar medium or large depend on you. This widget is new in flutter 3.3 so just update SDK to using it.
In MaterialApp you need to specify:

```
theme: ThemeData(useMaterial3: true)
```

And then in Scaffold body:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverAppBar.medium(
        title: const Text('Your tittle of page'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.abc)),
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.abc_outlined)),
        ],
      ),
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Text('Content of page'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```